# How to retrieve subclasses as tuple of tuple

Tags: python, polymorphism

From `BaseClass.__subclasses__()` which is :

```
[ClassA, ClassB]
```

I want to get something like:

```
((ClassA, ), (ClassB, ))
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
[tuple(x()) for x in BaseClass.__subclasses__()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
tuple((x,) for x in BaseClass.__subclasses__())
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> class BaseClass:
...     pass
...
>>> class ClassA(BaseClass):
...     pass
...
>>> class ClassB(BaseClass):
...     pass
...
>>> BaseClass.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.ClassA'>, <class '__main__.ClassB'>]
>>>
>>> tuple((x,) for x in BaseClass.__subclasses__())
((<class '__main__.ClassA'>,), (<class '__main__.ClassB'>,))
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a list into a tuple where every list item is itself a one-tuple, try:

```
tuple(map(tuple, BaseClass.__subclasses__()))
```